# A question about a corollary of the Spectral Theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra

The following is a screenshot of the proof of the Spectral Theorem as given in Artin.

[image]

[image]

By what I've understood from the proof, if the basis is the set of mutually orthogonal eigenvectors of $T$, then the matrix of $T$ is diagonal, with the eigenvalues appearing in the diagonal.

I don't understand what the matrix $P$ is. I have been told that $P$ is the matrix with the orthonormal eigenvectors as columns. But that wouldn't make sense. It would mean that $AP=PD$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. However, isn't $A=D$, as determined in the proof above??

Comment: I think you took the meaning quite literally (correct me if not). When you say a matrix $A$ is diagonal w.r.to a basis $P$, it means that there exists a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $A=PDP^{-1}$. In common usage, $A$ is said to be diagonal w.r.to $P$. Let $P=[p1,\dots,p_N]$ (column vectors). Then note that $A=PDP^{-1}$ implies $Ap_i=D_{i,i}p_i$

Answer (score 0):

Let me give an overview of the situation and hopefully that will clear a few things up.

First, given a linear operator $T$ and some basis $\mathcal{B}$, you have a representative matrix for $T$ with respect to $\mathcal{B}$, which we will denote by $[T]_\mathcal{B}$. Conversely, given a matrix $M$ and a basis $\mathcal{B}$, you can find a linear operator whose matrix representation with respect to $\mathcal{B}$ is $M$.

Suppose you have a linear operator $T$. For most basis, the matrix representation of $T$ will be rather bland. But for certain basis, in particular for a basis in which each vector is an eigenvector of $T$, your matrix representation is diagonal. Part **(a)** of the spectral theorem assures you that such a basis always exists for a Hermitian operator, and moreover the eigenvectors can be chosen to be orthonormal.

Now suppose you are given a Hermitian matrix $M$. Then this represents a Hermitian operator under some basis $\mathcal{B}$. In other words, we have some Hermitian operator $T$ for which $M = [T]_\mathcal{B}$. But by part **(a)** of our theorem, there exists an eigenbasis for $T$, say $\mathcal{C}$. We would like to represent $T$ under $\mathcal{C}$ rather $\mathcal{B}$, so we must apply a change-of-basis. Our change-of-basis matrix is precisely the matrix $P$ of eigenvectors. The act of diagonalization is really the change-of-basis to an eigenbasis, and part **(b)** of the theorem assures us that this is possible so long as the matrix is Hermitian.

So to answer your question, no $A$ is not equal to $D$, but they do represent the same Hermitian operator $T$. The matrix $A$ is the representation of $T$ under some choice of basis, while $D$ is the representation of $T$ under an eigenbasis. The matrix $P$ is the change-of-basis matrix into the eigenbasis.